# linux file compare string unincluded

Tags: linux, file, compare

how can i compare 2 files in LINUX containing for example:

file1

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

file2

```
1
2
3
```

and to get the result

file3

```
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`comm`: Select or reject lines common to two files?](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?comm)

```
comm -3 file1 file2 > file3
```

would work for your simple example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all the lines that are in file1, but not in file2, you can do this:

```
diff file1 file2 | grep "^<" | sed "s/^< //" > file3
```